# What does IRB use to determine how to represent a returned instance?

Tags: ruby, class, irb

Given a Ruby class:

```
class Foo
  def initialize(options={})
    @sensitive = options.delete :sensitive
  end
end
```

If I create an instance of that class in IRB, I get to see instance vars and memory address.

```
irb(main):002:0> Foo.new(sensitive: 'foo')
=> #<Foo:0x007fe766134a98 @sensitive="foo">
```

If I create an instance of AWS::S3, I don't:

```
irb(main):003:0> require 'aws-sdk'
=> true
irb(main):004:0> AWS::S3.new(access_key_id: 'aki', secret_access_key: 'sak')
=> <AWS::S3>
```

Note that `AWS::S3` is not a singleton (at least not in the sense of [explicitly including the Singleton module](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/singleton/rdoc/Singleton.html)).

Is there anything I can do to tell IRB not to output instance vars and/or memory address?

(I've already tried `.to_s` but I get a string containing the memory address for instances of both classes without any instance vars.)

Comment: If you start `irb --noecho`, it will suppress all IRB inspections. But I think this is not your question. IRB use [`#inpect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-inspect) method. Read the line from the doc *User defined classes should override this method to make better representation of obj. When overriding this method, it should return a string whose encoding is compatible with the default external encoding.*

Comment: @ArupRakshit Your comment is spot-on, you should turn it into an answer. It's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I don't know, if community would also agree with this. If they, I can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you start **IRB**  `irb --noecho`, it will suppress all IRB inspections. But I think this is not your question.

IRB use [`#inpect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-inspect) method. Read the line from the Documentation :

Returns a string containing a human-readable representation of `obj`. *By default*, show the *class name and the list of the instance variables and their values (by calling `inspect` on each of them). User defined classes should override this method to make better representation of `obj`*. When *overriding* this method, it should return a *string* whose encoding is compatible with the **default external encoding**.

Example :

```
class Foo
   def initialize
      @x = 10
   end
   # customized inspection
   def inspect
    "0x%7x" % self.object_id.to_s
   end
end

foo = Foo.new
foo # => 0x118e27c
```

Note : I used [`String#%`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-25) method inside my customized `#inspect` method.

Answer (score 2):

The standard method being used to render human-readable debugging output (not just in IRb but in general, e.g. on Rails error pages etc.) is `#inspect`. Depending on which extensions you loaded, your command line options or whether you are using Pry instead of IRb, it may also look for a `#pretty_inspect` first.

Comment: Which uses pretty_inspect? I didn't know about that one, but would like to use it under some circumstances.

Comment: Not sure. I have `pry-full` installed and use that exclusively, and it uses `pretty_inspect` by default, which for example produces nicely indented nested arrays or hashes.

Comment: Okay, cool; I thought that was coming from awesome_print. Thanks!